# How to know which .net framework is required for my program?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-framework-version

I devoloped a program for my pharmacy under (windows xp)  using (vb 10 express)
i send it to a friend who has a windows 7 computer and it failed to run the program

When i tried to run the program in virtual machine ( windows xp) i found that it required (dotnetfx35.exe) and (dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe) and run succesfully.

my friend installed 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718  and
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=1639 and
he was unable to install a 3.5 frame work !!

How do I know what frameworks my application will require when I publish them?

Comment: i am sorry the problem was in my fiend machine !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project `properties` > `Application` There you see target framework. Target machine should have that version of .Net framework to run the application successfully.

Comment: in the references my application use framework 4
but on  my fried  machine did not run

Comment: I think you may be limited to the 4.0 Client on XP, not the full 4.0 Framework. For a desktop app the 4.0 Client is probably adequate.